# Same adjectives, different meanings used together in same sentence

Tags: grammaire, sens, adjectifs

If I can say:

> Un grand homme ( = célèbre )

and

> Un homme très grand ( = de grand taille )

It seems to me that I could use both meanings in same sentence:

> Un grand homme très grand ( = de grand taille et aussi célèbre )

Is this correct?

Other examples:

> Une curieuse fille curieuse
>
> Un cher stylo très cher etc.

Comment: C'est très rarement utilisé, et seulement pour faire un jeu de mots. On peut aussi avoir un double sens sans la répétition: par exemple au début d'un courrier adressé au fisc: _Cher Trésor_. Pour des figures de style analogues, voir [zeugma](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_(stylistique))

Comment: @mouviciel Le langage à utiliser ici est-il le français ou l'anglais svp? Je suis un petit nouveau :)

Comment: @mouviciel Je pense que vous pouvez utiliser les deux parce que je les parle ( et c'est moi qui ai posé le question ) mais peut-être il vaut mieux d'écrire en anglais pour que tout le monde puisse comprendre votre réponse.

Comment: @Nathan: sur ce site consacré à l’usage de la langue française ce serait dommage de s’ en priver

Comment: Je suis ici pour apprendre francais. Je clairement preferais [?] lire les questions et les responses en francais, bien que, peut-etre, mois aussi pourrais etre forcé à poser une question en anglais parce que je ne suis pas assez fluent en francais... Mais la préference et: francais!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repetition would sound a bit weird. You can avoid it and still point out you want to use both meanings of an adjective with this turn of phrase:

"C'était un très grand homme, dans les deux sens du terme".

Answer (score 1):

Though it is gramatically correct, you may want to refrain from using it. It may seem like a subjective argument, but in french we tend to avoid at all cost the repetition of the same words. Especially in your examples: mixing the two kind of adjectives (before and after) can easily lead to confusion. It is used in poetry as a stylish effect, but never in a normal conversation.